# Convert Rows and Columns of CSV file into numpy arrays

Tags: python, csv, numpy-ndarray

I have a csv file like this:

```
       l1 p1 p2 p3 ... p784
1       ↑ ← - - r o w - - →
.       c ← - - r o w - - →
.       o ← - - r o w - - →
.       l ← - - r o w - - →
27454   ↓ ← - - r o w - - →

# rows: 27454 cols: 784
```

I want to convert it into two numpy arrays like this using the **csv module**...
`l=[ ←, c, o, l, → ] #size: 27454`
and

```
r = [ [ ←, -, -, r, o, w, -, -, → ],
      [ ←, -, -, r, o, w, -, -, → ],
      [ ←, -, -, r, o, w, -, -, → ] ]
#size : (27454, 784)
```

further I want to split the **r array** of `#shape: (27454, 784)` into `#shape: (27454, 28,28)`

How to get these arrays ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Do this:

(**path** is the path to your csv file)

```
fields = []
rows = []

with open(path, 'r') as csv_f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_f)
    
    rows = [r for r in csv_reader]
    l = np.array([r[0] for r in rows])
    i_ = np.array([r[1:] for r in rows])
    i = np.array([np.array_split(r, 28) for r in i_])
    i = i.astype(int)

print(labels.shape)
print(images.shape)
print(l.shape)
```

### output:

```
(27454,)
(27454, 784)
(27454, 28, 28)
```